# Precompact on $ {C}\left[{0,1}\right] $

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Is that function family $x_n(t) = n^{-(t+\frac{1}{2})}$,  where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, precompact on $C[0, 1]$?

To solve this, I used Ascoli's theorem on the continuity of a family of functions.

1. To begin with, I found out that the family of functions is bounded, i.e. $0 \lt x_n(t) \le 1$.
2. Then it's worth finding out the following: $\forall \varepsilon \gt 0\, \exists \delta = \delta(\varepsilon) \gt 0: \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: |t_1 -t_2| \lt \delta \implies |x_n(t_1) - x_n(t_2)| \lt \varepsilon$.

I have no other ideas except to use the Lagrange theorem, but $\max|x_n'(t)|=0$.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a family of equi-Lipschitz functions $(f_n)\subset C([a,b])$, i.e. a family of Lipschitz functions with the same Lipschitz constant, which is bounded in a point $t_0\in[a,b]$. Then $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded and continuous, so, thanks to the Ascoli-Arzelà theorem, we can conclude that $(f_n)$ is precompact on $C([a,b])$. In fact we know there exists two constants $k,c\geq 0$ such that $$|f_n(s)-f_n(t)|\leq k|s-y|,\:\forall s,t\in[a,b],\:\forall n\in \mathbb N$$
and $$|f_n(t_0)|\leq c,\:\forall n\in\mathbb N$$

$1$. Let's prove that the family $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded. For all $n\in \mathbb N$ and for all $t\in[a,b]$ we have that:
$$|f_n(t)|\leq |f_n(t)-f_n(t_0)|+|f_n(t_0)|\leq k|t-t_0|+c\leq k|a-b|+c$$

$2$. Given $\varepsilon>0$ we choose $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{k}$. For all $n\in\mathbb N$ and for all $s,t\in[a,b]$ s.t. $|s-t|<\delta$ we have that: $$|f_n(s)-f_n(t)|\leq k|s-t|<k\delta=\varepsilon$$ so  $(f_n)$ is uniformly continuous.

A special case of what said before is when $(f_n)\subset C^1([a,b])$ and there exists a constant $c\geq 0$ independent on $n$ s.t. $\left \| f'_n \right \|\leq c$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. It's easy to see that such a family is equi-Lipschitz, so if it also bounded at a point then $(f_n)$ is precompact on $C([a,b])$.

Considering $f_n(t)=x_n(t)=n^{-(t+\frac{1}{2})}$ on $C([0,1])$ we notice that:

$\bullet$ $\left \| x'_n \right \|=\frac{\log(n)}{\sqrt n}<1$ for all $n\in\mathbb N_{>0}$

$\bullet$ $|x_n(0)|=\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\leq 1$ for all $n\in \mathbb N_{>0}$

Comment: what is k in our case?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using the supremum norm on $C[0,1]$.

$0 \leq x_n(t) \leq n^{-1/2}$ so $x_n \to 0$ uniformly. Any convergent sequence in  a metric space is precompact.

Theorem:

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $x_n \to x$ in $X$ then $\{x,x_1,x_2,\cdots\}$ is a  compact set.

Proof: If $(U_i)$ is an open cover of $\{x,x_1,x_2,\cdots\}$ the ther exists $i_0$ such that $x \in U_{i_0}$. Since $x_n \to x$ there exists $N$ such that $x_n \in U_{i_0}$ for all $n >N$. For $n=1,2,\cdots, N$ there exist $i_n$ such that $x_n \in U_{i_N}$. We have now obtained a finite number of $U_i$'s which include the entire set $\{x,x_1,x_2,\cdots\}$.

Comment: What's the theorem?

Comment: I have included a proof . @Gyerzix

Comment: Thanks, but if this family functions copmact, is it precompact?

Comment: If a set is compact then any subset is precompact. @Gyerzix